# How to make list multi items(image and text) in alertdialog

Tags: android, list, android-alertdialog

hii .. 
I want to make this kind alertdialog..

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-sending-pictures-the-easy-way/

can you help find a solution???
thanks before.. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [ArrayAdapter and AlertDialog for single choice items](http://mgmblog.com/2010/06/10/arrayadapter-and-alertdialog-for-single-choice-items/#more-178)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to produce what's depicted in the image:

```
 Cursor books = ((Activity)ctx).managedQuery(booksprovider.CONTENT_URI_BOOKS, null, 
            dbhelper.BOOKS_COLLECTION + " = ? AND "+ dbhelper.BOOKS_SHELF +" != ?", new String[]{ Strings.Library, String.valueOf(ShelfId) }, 
            dbhelper.BOOKS_ID+" DESC");
    final ListView booksToAdd = new ListView(ctx);

    SimpleCursorAdapter booksList = new dialogView(ctx, R.layout.shelves_add, books,
            new String[] { dbhelper.BOOKS_TITLE, dbhelper.BOOKS_AUTHOR },//columns to include in view 
            new int[] { R.id.search_results_title,  R.id.search_results_author }, ShelfId );//views to bind columns to

    booksToAdd.setAdapter(booksList);
    booksToAdd.setClickable(true);
    alert.setView(booksToAdd);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Finished", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((shelves)context).adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }).show();

 R.layout.shelves_add contains the following:

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/solid_white"
android:padding="0dp" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imagedescrip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_results_title"
    android:src="@drawable/book_tab" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search_results_title"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/solid_black"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search_results_author"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_results_title"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="18dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/solid_black"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/selected_box"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/search_results_title"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/checkbox" />
```

This is what I get:
[image: Context menu alert dialog]

Comment: you answer is incorrect because question ask about list of multi item (image + text). anyway thank you!